# Installed pyside for python 2.7 from binary but is missing the link to the DLL for qt

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I installed the binary pyside from the unofficial binary site and I get the error

```
>>> import PySide
>>> import PySide.QtCore
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Now googling the problem it says that there should be an environment variable for QT but there wasn't one created when the binary package was installed. My site packages folder contains the dlls for QT but adding that to the path didnt work either. Any ideas?

I probably have kivy and annaconda (which i dont use) on my system if that is causing conflicts, but i see nothing in my path pointing to that.

Comment: Why did you not install pyside via PIP ? Official PySide binaries installed via PIP are well supported.

Comment: Ok, sorted. I had an old version of PIP. Thanks for forcing me to look again at PIP!